# SIP forwarding based on location

Tags: sip, freeswitch, vonage

I have a DID from nexmo with voice support and I added SIP forwarding to one of my freeswitch servers (B). I have two freeswitch servers A (asia) and B (europe), If a caller calls from Asia, how do I make sure it gets routed to A server so its close to the user?

Based on my research I might need to do lua scripting for dynamic dialplan with redirect. But even this, I'm not even sure how to get the caller's location so I can decide if to which server to route the call.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

what do you know about the caller?

If it's the IP address, then a lookup in WHOIS database should work. Also there are projects like freegeoip.net that deliver you the geographical location for an IP address.

Otherwise, if caller's phone number is only know, then you need to have a database of all country codes around the world, and build your lookup logic based on that.

Comment: Yes I know about that what I'm after is routing from one freeswitch to another. Once I know then to redirect to server A, in freeswitch how do I go about redirecting the call?

Comment: better place a SIP proxy, like Kamailio or OpenSIPS in front of FreeSWITCH servers, and let it send the INVITE's to the one that is needed. Then the RTP media will take the optimal path.